# PHP strtotime relative time format got bug (or feature?)

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I found that strtotime is behaving strange when using relative time format.

Assume today is 31st March, 2015 (done by setting system clock), when I use `strtotime('-1 month')`, it returns 3rd March, 2015.

Assume today is 31st July, 2015, when I use `strtotime('-1 month')`, it returns 1st July, 2015, while it returns 31st July, 2015 if today is 31st August, 2015.

So, it seems that PHP is just subtracting 1 month and add the date back if that month doesn't have the 31st day (or 30th & 29th for February). Is it a bug of PHP? Or is there a reason that PHP makes it that way as a feature?

And most importantly, no matter if it is bug or feature, is there a way I can make it always returning the last day when calculating time? (there will be case of -3 months or other number of months, so "last day of last month" is not okay)

Comment: Start by defining what exactly "-1 month" means on a 31st. It's such a wishy-washy definition that I would never expect any software to "get it right" to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$d = new DateTime( '2010-01-08' );
$d->modify('+1 month');
$d->modify( 'last day of this month' );
echo $d->format('d-M-Y'), "\n";
?>
```

Comment: What if it is -1 month? This will just do nothing if $d = new DateTime('2010-03-01');

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Just edit the date to: '2010-03-01' like you said, and change it to '-1 month'. Output is as expected.

Comment: ops, sorry, the problem should be occuring at 2010-03-31.

Comment: I tried [searching](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=22486) it for a bit and this even happens when working with timestamps. Not sure what's the case.

Comment: Well, that is the reason I am asking. Would you mind deleting the answer? Having an answer makes the question less noticeable by other from outside. They would think someone has already solved the problem.